# Private event handlers in Backbone Views

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-views

I'm trying to figure out a way to keep my private functions and helper methods truly private. Each object should only publicize what is allowed to be called externally (radical, I know!). I'm having a hard time doing this with Backbone views in a way that:

1. Doesn't sacrifice readability
2. Doesn't involve a lot of boilerplate
3. Doesn't have any unintended consequences

Here's my general View structure:

```
(function(){
    //Private function no other view needs to care about
    var addStuffToMyDom = function(model){
        var newView = new Subview({model: model});

        //Problem: this doesn't refer to the 'view' here
        this.$el.append(newView.render().$el);
    }

    //Another trivial function which should really be private
    var doSomeThingTrivial = function(){
        this.$el.addClass("meh");
    }

    return BaseView.extend({
        events: {
            "click": doSomeThingTrivial
        },

        render: function(){
            var me = this;
            this.collection.each(addStuffToMyDom);
            return this;
        }
    });
 }());
```

As you can see the private functions can't reference 'this' to append themselves to.

Solution 1:

```
(function(){
    var me;

    ...

    return BaseView.extend({
        initialize: function(){
            me = this;
        }
    });
}());
```

This has a lot of subtle side-effects + would be annoying to have to do this every time.

Solution 2:

```
(function(){
    var me;

    ...

    return BaseView.extend({
        events{
            "click" : function(){
                doSomeThingTrivial.call(this);
            }
        }
    });
}());
```

This works, but it's a lot of boilerplate for messy code.

Solution 3:

```
(function(){
    return BaseView.extend({
            events: {..}
        initialize: function(){
            _.bindAll(this, this.events);
        }
    });
}());
```

I like this the best; this works, is fairly readable and works as advertised, but again, is one extra step to do for each view. Any other solutions I'm missing?

Comment: Why not just pass the function body of `doSomethingTrivial` directly to the event? That way it exists only as the anonymous event handler and not as an object method on your class/view/whatever.

Comment: @Mathletics possible, but if it grew 'not so trivial' in the future it'll leave behind a huge events hash.

Comment: I don't see a real use case where you would want to force something that is not event supported in current JavaScript implementation. From my experience on small and large projects, it is better to keep a good communication between team members and document which methods are there for everyone and which ones not. Also, if you intend to reuse your "classes", by arranging the code inside closures will really make your life harder. I really recommend you to try out this  combo: RequireJS + Backbone + Backbone-Super.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Discovered that _.bindAll(this) in the initializer fixes scope issues in the private function. I've grown less convinced of this design pattern since I asked this question, but it does solve it :)

```
(function(){
    //Private function no other view needs to care about
    var addStuffToMyDom = function(model){
        var newView = new Subview({model: model});

        //Problem: this doesn't refer to the 'view' here
        this.$el.append(newView.render().$el);
    }

    //Another trivial function which should really be private
    var doSomeThingTrivial = function(){
        this.$el.addClass("meh");
    }

    return BaseView.extend({
        events: {
            "click": doSomeThingTrivial
        },

        initialize: function(){
            _.bindAll(this);

        }
    });
 }());
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the context you want to use to the `each` method:

`this.collection.each(addStuffToMyDom, this);`

Now `this` will be your view inside `addStuffToMyDom`.

I thought when you use the Backbone events hash to hook up events, it did something similar. Are you sure `this` is not the view inside `doSomeThingTrivial`?

If you look at Backbone `delegateEvents`, it does this:

`method = _.bind(method, this);`

Where `this` is your view.